# Access RunTime Error 2501 - OpenQuery Action Cancelled

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Trying to piece together an old database written by a previous employee, but when running the Macro in excel to link back to the access database I get the runtime error 2501, the code is given below does anyone have any ideas?

```
Public Sub Auto_Open()
    If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then Exit Sub
    Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    accApp.Visible = False
    accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("i:\database reporting\main.mdb")
    accApp.DoCmd.OpenQuery "blp_varience_estimate2"
    accApp.Quit
    Sheets("Estimate Raw").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Normally error 2501 should be just ignored. Please check the query: open mdb directly and run the query. It should not give any errors.

Comment: Yeah i thought that, but if i skip past that and ignore it, i get the following

RunTime Error 2001
You Cancelled the previous operation

Comment: Is "blp_varience_estimate2" an UPDATE query? What does it do?

Comment: Yeah its runs the query in access to pull from other tables

Answer (score 1):

`DoCmd.OpenQuery` opens a query for viewing, and shows warning boxes on action queries. The error you're seeing refers to a cancel action on the warning box, which is probably not showing as Access itself isn't showing and thus auto-cancels.

The proper way to run queries from VBA is through the QueryDefs collection:
`CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyQuery").Execute`

Edit your code to the following:

```
Public Sub Auto_Open()
    If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then Exit Sub
    Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    accApp.Visible = False
    accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("i:\database reporting\main.mdb")
    accApp.CurrentDb.QueryDefs("blp_varience_estimate2").Execute
    accApp.Quit
    Sheets("Estimate Raw").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub
```

Note that setting `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` before executing the query probably works too, but my solution is more clean (just executes the query instead of hiding warnings, then executing a query and then trying to show the result to the user)